# user clicks on save button on a pop up window refresh main window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have calender which allows user to create edit and delete appointments.

when user click on new appointment button to create appointment it opens a window on top of calender window.Once user fill the fields and click on save button it saves data in to the databse.Up to now it is working great.

But it is not showing event immediately on the calender untill user refresh the calender.

I want to implement refresh functionality on save button.

Can anyone help me how to implement,

when user clicks on save button 1). Save the data in to the database. and 2). refresh main window(calender).

I tried using reload() on save but it reloads the current window(Pop up) and makes all fields empty.

Please find the code below.

```
$("#Savebtn").click(function() { 
    if(validate()){
      $("#fmEdit").submit(); 
      location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: You can manipulate the parent window by using `window.opener`

Answer (score 4):

give this a try:

```
window.parent.location.reload();
```

or(without jquery)

```
window.opener.location.reload(false);
```

then your code will be:

```
$("#Savebtn").click(function() { 
    if(validate()){
      $("#fmEdit").submit(function(){ 
          window.opener.location.reload(false);
      });
 }
});
```

Comment: I used window.parent.location.reload(); it solved my problem. Thankyou so much

Comment: The solution which you gave is worked fine on local server. But when I placed code on server its refeshing the main window without saving data. How can I overcome this problem on the server.

Comment: is it ?? i think we need to check the completion of the submit event.  i have made a minor change .. check if it works. code updated!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution.But now it is not submitting the form(Save button is not working).